# What a connect message header should look like in http2?

Tags: http, http2, nghttp2

I found that a get message header looks like:

```
:method: GET
:scheme: https
:authority: server.net
:path: /config
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip,deflate
```

What a connect message header should look like?

This example is from the RFC of http2:

```
GET /resource HTTP/1.1           HEADERS
     Host: example.org          ==>     + END_STREAM
     Accept: image/jpeg                 + END_HEADERS
                                          :method = GET
                                          :scheme = https
                                          :path = /resource
                                          host = example.org
                                          accept = image/jpeg
```

I want to know the equivalent of the connect header in http2.
In Http1 is:

```
CONNECT example.org:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org:443
```

Comment: Are you referring to the `CONNECT` request message when using an HTTP proxy?

Comment: yes, I try to send a connect message in http2 to the server and the server response is 400 (bad request)

Comment: Can you edit your post to provide what the actual request you're sending looks like?

Comment: I edited it, it's looks like that

Comment: It's quite difficult to understand how to answer this question, as HTTP2 is a binary protocol, the format you've listed above is a plain-text representation of what is being transmitted.  For connecting to a server as a client, you can read RFC at https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7540#section-3

Comment: ok, you are right. My question is not very good. I should mention that I want to use nghttp2 library. I already read the RFC and I know that all http1.x/http2 messages are sent in binary format. My problem is that I cant understand the connect method in http2.  I understand from RFC that the ":scheme" and ":path" pseudo-header fields MUST be omitted, so I put in the header just :method and :authority, and message looks in plain/text like: :method: CONNECT \n :authority: server.net

Comment: My server answers well at GET and POST messages, but at CONNECT not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of the `CONNECT` method in HTTP/2 is specified in [section 8.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7540#section-8.3).

With the formatting you used above looks like:

```
:method: CONNECT
:authority: proxy.net:8080
```

As specified, `:scheme` and `:path` *must* be omitted.

The HTTP/2 `CONNECT` method can also be used for bootstrapping other protocols (see for example [WebSocket over HTTP/2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8441)), so that, additionally, the `:protocol` pseudo-header may also be present.

Remember however that this is only a textual representation of HTTP/2; the bytes that actually travel over the network are different since you must encode them using [HPACK](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7541).

Unless you are actually writing an HTTP/2 implementation, it is better that you use existing libraries (available in virtually any programming language) to send HTTP/2 requests (of any kind): the libraries will take care of converting your `CONNECT` request into the proper bytes to send over the network.

Comment: What should the header look like if the proxy has both a username and a password?

Comment: and what about Proxy-Authenticate and Proxy-Authorization?

Comment: Non-pseudo headers are present as usual, like in any HTTP request. They are HPACK-encoded like the pseudo-headers. The difference in a HTTP/2 `CONNECT` request is the absence of pseudo-headers that are otherwise mandatory, and the possible presence of the `:protocol` pseudo-header.